# Identifying location on unicode error

Tags: unicode

I am knitting my document using `bookdown` in `rmarkdown`. I'm getting this error

```
 LaTeX Error: Unicode character Í¾ (U+037E)
```

I've tried searching the .tex file but not found where this is in my document. Any ideas on how I could find it?

Comment: The full error message that you have not shown highlights the exact place in the source or use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{037E}{!!!!FIX ME}` and see where that gets typeset

Comment: U+0037E is Greek question mark `;` so it looks like a semi colon `;` but semantically it's a `?`